# I am unable to share the url on linked-in through linked-in SDKs which they provide

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am using this code for this sharing . I update my plist with api key and also i have linked-in app on my iPhone.

I am getting success message but url not showing on linked-in page.

```
- (IBAction)linkedinShare:(id)sender {

    NSString *url = @"http://www.tripadvisor.com";


    if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession])
    {
       [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance]postRequest:url body:nil success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response)
         {
             if (response)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Linkedin" message:@"Linkedin done" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];


             }

             NSLog(@"Success is");

        } error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",apiError);

        }];
```

Comment: move nslog into your if condition and see if u still see the success message or not

Comment: response is not nil and success message coming  in that condition also.